# How could passwords on OSX keychain for one user end up in another?

Tags: macos, apple-id, password, keychain, user-account

Our home MacBook has two users on it: my wife's and mine.  This morning we noticed when logged in as my wife's user that in the KeyChain Access it has all of my web passwords.  Including passwords I only use on my work laptop.  How is this possible?

To clarify exactly what's going on let's define some things:

- MacBooks

  - Home-macbook
  - Husband-work-macbook
- Apple/iTunes accounts

  - Wife-apple-account
  - Husband-apple-account
- OSX users on home-macbook

  - Wife-osx-user (uses Wife-apple-account)
  - Husband-osx-user (uses Husband-apple-account)
- OSX users on work-macbook

  - Employee-osx user (uses Husband-apple-account)

So this is what happened exactly:  On Home-macbook, logged in as Wife-osx-user, we could see passwords in the KeyChain Access program that were *only* *ever* *used* on work-macbook as Employee-osx.

Now if Employee-osx passwords showed up on Home-macbook when logged into Husband-osx-user, that could make some sense.  But why are the passwords being shared between users?  Are they linked through OSX somehow and can I turn that off?

One important note is that this home-macbook was recently upgraded from Snow Leopard to Yosemite.

**Update**

When I delete these passwords from the KeyChain Access app, they almost immediately are re-added automatically!  How can I stop this?!

Comment: Under the iCloud system Preference which user is logged in on the work-macbook and Home-macbook

Comment: On Work-macbook the iCloud user is Husband-apple-account.  On home-macbook logged in as wife-osx-user, iCloud is not logged in.  ///something else freaky happening too, adding info above

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I have logged into Chrome under wife-osx-user.  Chrome saves passwords into keychain.   And then keychain makes those available to Safari.  Not AT ALL the desired behavior but I suppose it makes some sense.